the messages I receive in the consoleLog element and in the console itself, are duplicated
the messages I receive in the consoleLog element and in the console itself, are duplicated and I can't figure out why.  I'm using NodeJS, Express
A form submission kicks off a python script.  The console print and progress bar is captured and added to corresponding elements on the webpage. I'm not that experienced with nodejs much less express.
Client Side
$(document).ready(function() {
          const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

          ws.onmessage = function(event) {
            try {
              const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
              if (data.type === 'error' && data.message.includes("Image Files:")) {
                const progressMatch = data.message.match(/Image Files:.*?(\d+)%/);
                if (progressMatch && progressMatch.length > 1) {
                  const progressPercentage = parseInt(progressMatch[1], 10);
                  $('#progressBar')
                    .addClass('bg-info') // Make the bar blue
                    .css('width', progressPercentage + '%')
                    .attr('aria-valuenow', progressPercentage)
                    .text(progressPercentage + '% Complete');
                }
              } else if (data.type === 'error' && data.message.includes("Current file:")) {
                const currentFileMatch = data.message.match(/Current file: (.*?\.(jpg|tif|png|JPG|TIF|PNG))/);
                if (currentFileMatch && currentFileMatch.length > 1) {
                  $('#currentImage').text(`Processing: ${currentFileMatch[1]}`);
                }
              } else if (data.type === 'log') {
                var logMessage = data.message.replace(/\u001b\[.*?m/g, ''); // Removes ANSI color codes
                $('#consoleLog').append(logMessage + '\n');
              } else if (data.type === 'missionComplete') {
                // Create and append the "Review Missions" button if not already present
                if (!$('#review').length) { // Checks if the button doesn't exist
                  const reviewButton = $('<button id="review" class="btn btn-success mt-3">Review Missions</button>')
                    .click(function() {
                      pageReset();
                      window.location.href = '/missions';
                    });
                  // Append the button to a specific container or directly to the body
                  $('body').append(reviewButton);
                } else {
                  // If the button exists but is hidden, simply show it
                  $('#review').removeClass('invisible');
                }
              }

            } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error processing WebSocket message:', error);
            }
          };

Server Side
const express = require('express');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 6060 });

const broadcastMessage = (message) => {
  wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
    if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      client.send(JSON.stringify(message));
    }
  });
};

pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', data => {
  const message = { type: 'log', message: data.toString() };
  broadcastMessage(message);
});

pythonProcess.stderr.on('data', data => {
  const message = { type: 'error', message: data.toString() };
  broadcastMessage(message);
});

let responseSent = false;

pythonProcess.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`Python script exited with code ${code}`);
  broadcastMessage({ type: 'missionComplete' });

  if (!responseSent) {
    responseSent = true;
    if (code !== 0) {
      res.status(500).send('Error processing images.');
      clearDirectory(uploadsPath)
      clearDirectory(downloadsPath)
    } else {
      res.status(200).send('Images processed successfully.');
    }
  }
});

  wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    console.log('WebSocket client connected');
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
      console.log('received: %s', message);
    });
  });

});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(`Incoming request: ${req.method} ${req.path}`);
  next();
});

I've tried several approaches and coPilot was NO help.  One msg per action. That's all.
